# Changing background color of birt report according to groups

Tags: scripting, birt

[image]

I am generating a BIRT report as shown by image embedded, I am grouping by custmeer such as ACM , AFL etc ...

As you can see I use background alternative color as blue and white, to achieve this I simply use the highlight tab of detail row as(row["__rownum"] % 2 Equal to 0).

now , if I move into more complexity such as different color combination for different groups e.g for group(customer in this case) yellow-white, for group2 red-white etc....

I am using this.getStyle().backgroundColor ='color', but the problem lies into selecting the individual groups, may be some sort of in condition would do the trick, but I am lost

Comment: Are you likely to have a relatively small number of groups/colours, or a very large number? (The answer would determine the easiest way of doing this.)

Comment: @mark  .. these groups are nothing but report parameters...  could range anything between 20-30

Comment: @mark...lets make things simpler , for every alternate group , bakground color should change ..e.g  , for group 1 (red-yellow ) group2 (white-blue) group3(again red-yellow) group4 (while-blue)......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to set a row's background colour in BIRT is by adding conditions to the list in the Highlight tab within the Property Editor for the row. It looks as though you have already done this to set alternative lines to blue - by adding extra conditions with additional colours, you can set the background accordingly. This method is most useful where only a small number of colours are required, since you have to set up a different condition for each colour.

Where a larger selection of colours is likely to be required, it would make more sense to do conditional formatting within an event script - you can find an example [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yHqyu_Gx1UcC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=birt%20background%20color%20event%20script%20-chart&source=bl&ots=drO8sh2l47&sig=UO7fDu7hRggCEBYue-KgUFO6x3o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m7nxTrK6I8q38QO-zbWjAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=birt%20background%20color%20event%20script%20-chart&f=false).

EDIT: Adding a running group count in BIRT:

- Add an aggregation item to your table - you can do this by dragging an aggregation item from the Quick Tools section of the Palette, for example.
- In the Aggregation Builder dialog, set the Function to be COUNT, the expression to be 1 and the Aggregate On to be the group you want to count (eg. Customer)
- Insert a second aggregation item with the Function set to be RUNNINGCOUNT, the expression to be `1/row[`*first aggregation name*`]` and the Aggregate On to be Table.

The second aggregation item will be a running count of the groups in the report.

Comment: @ mark .... ok it seems to be working but here i thee issue 
if(this.getRowData( ).getColumnValue("per_Name").toString().length() %2 == 0) {
this.getStyle( ).backgroundColor = "yellow";
this.getStyle().color="Red";
 } ---   So it cheak for every customer name count the length of it and accourding to the lenth(%2==0)it'll apply stayles , so report is now depend on the length of the name .......is there is any way  to get the indexes custmer wise ...

Comment: @vibhor: how would you want to determine the background colour?

Comment: Since our name is a string not an int , so if we have to hard code it as (this.getRowData( ).getColumnValue("per_Name") =='AFL') (this.getRowData( ).getColumnValue("per_Name") =='ABCD)'......for every parameter we have to hard code .....how to iterate our customers..

Comment: @vibhor: I appreciate that you do not want to hardcode a separate value for each customer. However, I do not know how you want to determine which colours should go to which customers. Do you want them to be random?

Comment: ...just alternative ... custmer1 (blue-white)    ..custumer2(red-yellow)   again customer 3 (blue-white)   ..customer 4 (red-yellow).........and so on

Comment: I suggest setting up a runningcount of group number (in either SQL or BIRT, whichever is most convenient) and making the colour conditional on the modulus of that by 2, as well as the modulus of the row number by 2.

Comment: ....apologies for late reply ... if we do the same in sql the n it will rip it off our data (custmers)into half........so Sql isnt a good idea,...using BIRT i don't have clue how to achieve that .....

Comment: "if we do the same in sql the n it will rip it off our data (custmers)into half" - not necessarily; it depends on which version of SQL you are using and whether it supports analytic functions. See the amended answer for how to do this in BIRT.